# ACL admin routing redirecting issue in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.3

I have followed 
[this tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html).

I have used prefix in core.php
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));

when i try to login http://ifs.com/admin/users/login

I am getting this error. "The page isn't redirecting properly".

Can anyone help me to setup ACL for admin & normal user login.

Comment: I think this is too general you have to help a little and be more specific. For example do you have an admin_login function in your users controller;

Comment: If you're new to CakePHP, I would HIGHLY suggest NOT using ACL.  Even if you're an old pro, I would still suggest not using it.  Maybe in 3.0, it'll be better (haven't tried/looked), but in 2.x, it's more work than it's worth IMO.

Comment: @MponosGeorge Yes, I do have admin_login function in my Users Controller.